# ng-button error not working showing only one message angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Getting only one message  Please enter first name after entering the name too can you pls suggest i am very new in angular js please suggest how to stop erroring if first name enter

```
 <div class="text-input">
    <label for="player-firstname">First Name *</label>
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle success" ng-show="signup.userInfo.playerFirstname.$valid"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-times-circle error" ng-show="signup.userInfo.playerFirstname.$invalid && !signup.userInfo.playerFirstname.$pristine">Pls Enter First Name</i>
    <input type="text"
      placeholder="James"
      id="player-firstname"
      name="playerFirstname"
      ng-model="player.first_name"
      tabindex="1"
      required>
  </div>
<div class="black-button medium-button float-right" ng-if="signup.$invalid">
  <button ng-click="formError()" tabindex="15"><span class="button-text">Create Account
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
  </button>
</div>
angular.module('users.players.signup', ['vcRecaptcha', 'services.errors'])
  .controller('playerSignup', ['user', '$scope', '$log', '$location', '$http', '$timeout', 'auth', 'vcRecaptchaService', '$routeParams', '$rootScope', 'DateUtility', 'notify', function (user, $scope, $log, $location, $http, $timeout, auth, vcRecaptchaService, $routeParams, $rootScope, DateUtility, notify) {
    'use strict';

    $scope.process

$scope.formError = function(){
      $scope.process = true;
      if($scope.first_name == null){
        notify.message("Pls enter first name");
        $scope.process = false;
        return;
      }
    }
```

Comment: can any one suggest pls

Answer (score 0):

`ng-click="formError()"` should be `ng-click="formErrors()"` for one - not sure if that's the only issue but should move things along.

Comment: itamar its ok on writing it added errors no worry about it